# How to add extra data to a tree item?

Tags: c++, treeview, wxwidgets, treeviewitem

I'm trying to add extra data to a wx Tree Item using `wxTreeItemData`, but I cannot construct a `wxTreeItemData` object, because the constructor doesn't have any parameters.

Here is my sample code:

```
wxTreeCtrl treeCtrl = new wxTreeCtrl(parentWindow);
treeCtrl->AddRoot("Root");
treeCtrl->AppendItem(root, "item", -1,-1, "some extra data");
/** Signature help for inline ​​​wxTreeItemId​ ​‌​​AppendItem​(const ​​​wxTreeItemId​ &​​‌parent​, const ​​​wxString​ &​​‌text​, int ​​‌image​ = -1, int ​​‌selImage​ = -1, ​​​wxTreeItemData​ *​​‌data​ = (​​​wxTreeItemData​ *)0). Summary: insert a new item in as the last child of the parent. Current parameter 3 of 5: , . **/
```

This gives me an error:

```
E0413. no suitable conversion function from "std::string" to "wxTreeItemData *" exists
```

But when I pass a `wxTreeItemData` object nothing happens, because the object is empty.

The `wxTreeItemData` constructor is without any parameters!

Does anyone know how to add data to a `wxTreeItemData` object?

### Another try

I declared a new class that is derived from the `wxTreeItemData` class, then added a string that will hold the data, and then, I declared, and defined a method to return the data.
Code sample:

```
wxTreeItemId item = treeCtrl->AppendItem(Root, "item", -1,-1, new DataItem("some extra data"));
// It should set the new DataItem object as a wxTreeItemData
// I'll try to get the data object from the TreeCtrl:
DataItem *data = treeCtrl->GetItemData(item);
// Signature help for virtual ​​​wxTreeItemData​ * ​‌​​GetItemData​(const ​​​wxTreeItemId​ &​​‌item​) const.
// Trying to print the data:
std::cout << data->GetData();
// It should print the data.
```

Error:

```
E0144. a value of type "wxTreeItemData *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "DataItem *"
```

Because the method `GetItemData()` returns a wxTreeItemData object.
And if I tried to replace the `DataItem` to wxTreeItemData, I cannot invoke the `GetData()` method of my DataItem object.

### Helpful resources:

[wxWidgets: wxTreeCtrl Class Reference][1]

[wxWidgets: wxTreeItemData Class Reference](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_tree_item_data.html)

Comment: Not sure, but after a short look it looks like you should inherit from wxTreeItemData and add your variables in that subclass

Comment: As said above, you'll need to derive a class from wxTreeItemData and store your data in the derived class.

Comment: Please, review my changes.

Comment: I'm sorry if there are some stackoverflow errors.

Comment: @MEMOGAMER000, did you look at the `treectrl` sample?

Comment: You'll need to do something like `wxTreeItemData *data = treeCtrl->GetItemData(item);` and then cast data to your derived type.

Comment: Thank you all for your time!
This problem has been resolved, but I'm facing another problem if you can help:
When I try to append a new item to the TreeCtrl, I get an access violation error:
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFCCA0B7897 (comctl32.dll) in Application.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000000005976185A.
Then the visual studio opens the wx's Window.cpp file to try to understand the problem.
I think that this problem is caused by invoking the root item out of its thread?
Should I post a new question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You indeed need to derive your class from `wxTreeItemData`, as you've done, and you need to cast the returned value of `GetItemData()` to the correct value, i.e. write

```cpp
DataItem *data = static_cast<DataItem*>(treeCtrl->GetItemData(item));
```

This is safe as long as you only pass actual `DataItem` objects (and not something else) to `SetItemData()`.

Comment: Thank you for your time!
This problem has been resolved, but I'm facing another problem if you can help:
When I try to append a new item to the TreeCtrl, I get an access violation error:
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFCCA0B7897 (comctl32.dll) in Application.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000000005976185A.
Then the visual studio opens the wx's Window.cpp file to try to understand the problem.
I think that this problem is caused by invoking the root item out of its thread?
Should I post a new question?

Comment: Yes, you should post a new question.

Comment: This exception appears when I start debugging the application.  
However, the application runs without any problem!  
Thank you very much.

Comment: You do have a serious problem in your application if you get access violation exceptions, you can't just ignore it even if it gets caught somewhere else.